# bootstrap 4: center inline form inside a jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an inline form inside a jumbotron. I want to center it.

I tried using `text-align:center` on the jumbotron and it did center all the other elements inside the jumbotron except for the inline form element. So I don't know what is going wrong here.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="home">
  <h1 class="display-3">My Awesome App!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is why you should download this fantastic app!</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>Want to know more? Join our mailing list!</p>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <label class="sr-only" for="yourEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
      <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yourEmail" placeholder="Your Email">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```css
body{
  position: relative;
}

#home{
  background-image: url('../img/jumbotron-bkg-2.jpg');
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#yourEmail{
  width: 350px;
}

#about h2, #about-summary{
  text-align: center;
}

.card{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.card img{
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
}

#cards-container{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

#download{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  background-color: #0afff2;
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: @MichaelCoker bootstrap 4. The alpha version

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the `justify-content-center` helper class on the `form`. That will center the contents  with the flex property `justify-content: center;`

```css
#home{
  background-image: url('../img/jumbotron-bkg-2.jpg');
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron" id="home">
  <h1 class="display-3">My Awesome App!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is why you should download this fantastic app!</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>Want to know more? Join our mailing list!</p>
  <form class="form-inline justify-content-center">
    <label class="sr-only" for="yourEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
      <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yourEmail" placeholder="Your Email">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
</div>
```